# Error using jfree chart to generate piechart from mysql database

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to create a piechart using jfree chart with data from mysql database but l seem to be getting errors. Here is my code.

I have a LocationRepository where l implement my sql query

```
   public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Integer> {

       //hibernate query language (jpql)
       @Query("select type,count(type) from location group by type")
       public List<Object[]> findTypeAndTypeCout();

      }
```

I also have my ReportUtility Interface as follows

```
   public interface ReportUtil {

      void generatePieChart(String path, List<Object[]> data);

      }
```

Here is my ReportUtility implementation class

```
  @Component
  public class ReportUtilImpl implements ReportUtil {

    @Override
    public void generatePieChart(String path, List<Object[]> data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    for (Object[] objects : data) {
        dataset.setValue(objects[0].toString(), new Double(objects[1].toString()));
    }

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Location Type Report", dataset);

    try {
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(path+"/pieChart.jpeg"), chart, 300, 300);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Finally the Controller

```
   @Controller
    public class LocationController {

  @Autowired
  LocationService service;

  @Autowired
  LocationRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  ReportUtil reportUtil;

  @Autowired
  ServletContext sc;

  @RequestMapping("/generateReport")
   public String generateReport() {
     String path = sc.getRealPath("/");
     List<Object[]> data = repository.findTypeAndTypeCout();
     reportUtil.generatePieChart(path, data);
     return "report";

        }

     }
```

Now when l run this as a springboot application l get the following errors

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'locationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'locationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'locationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.jimadjei.location.repos.LocationRepository.findTypeAndTypeCout()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'locationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'locationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.jimadjei.location.repos.LocationRepository.findTypeAndTypeCout()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'locationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.jimadjei.location.repos.LocationRepository.findTypeAndTypeCout()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.jimadjei.location.repos.LocationRepository.findTypeAndTypeCout()!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: location is not mapped [select type,count(type) from location group by type]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, `LocationRepository` bean cannot be created. From your code `LocationRepository` is not made available to spring IOC.
Annotate your repository with `@Repository`, so spring creates the bean.

Updating the answer as per comments:

From the stack trace `QuerySyntaxException: location is not mapped`, `Location` entity is not created. So, either create it or use `@Query(nativeQuery=true)`

Comment: @John Have you created entity `Location`, which you are using in `@Query` ? The stacktrace says the same thing that `QuerySyntaxException: location is not mapped`

Comment: You can use `@Query(nativeQuery=true)` If you don't want to create JPA entity

Comment: thanks. @Query(value="select type,count(type) from location group by type", nativeQuery = true) was the right syntax.